# Can I Separate an object into many objects along UV seems?

Tags: uv

I am trying to make a folding animation of a complex model. I don't want to use the built in unfold process, because I want it to fold from flat islands into a 3d model. Because of the models complexity I found that the auto generated UV seams seem to work well for my purposes. I was hoping I could translate them in separate objects. I can't find any documentation on this and am fairly new to blender. Does anyone have a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Edit mode, select a seamed edge (red edge) then select: Select> Select Similar>Seam (If the seams aren't marked, go to UV editor, select everething and choose: UV> Seams from Island)
2. Choose: Edge> Mark Sharp
3. Go to Object mode and add an Edge Split modifier. Disable Edge Angle, then apply the modifier.
4. Go back to Edit mode and select Mesh> Separate> By Loose Parts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you rock! I love the internet :)!